# Table on Align in PHP

Tags: php

I try to configure the table in the output, seem the result is not align properly.

My code as follow:

```
<?php

$serverName ="192.168.1.40";
 $usr="Jack";
 $pwd="JackPass";
 $db="JackDB1";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT [Name], [Amount], [Billed]  FROM [Charge] WHERE [Name] like 'Antonio%' ";
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) 
 {
  echo("<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1 width=220>");
  echo("<tr>");
  echo("<td>".$row['Name']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Amount']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Billed']."</td>");
  echo("</tr>");
  echo("</table>");
 }  

?>
```

Comment: So what do you get ?

Comment: 1. The `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `border`, and `width` attributes are obsolete now, use CSS for table styling. 2. Column alignment must be set on every cell in the column to be reliable, I recommend using a CSS class on each cell for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the table outside of the while look since you only want to iterate over rows within the table, not creating a new table for every record:

```
echo("<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=1 width=220>");
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>".$row['Name']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Amount']."</td>"."<td>".$row['Billed']."</td>");
    echo("</tr>");

}
echo("</table>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the answer above. Printing the table outside of the while will make all the cells line up nicely. Give it a class to and use CSS to style it though instead of that old cellpadding and cellspacing etc.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I agree with the comment not answer, but his statement is accurate.